# when I create a user the user details stored in user table as well as I have to insert the username into another table also

Tags: laravel

I get this error `Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value`. But when MySQL turn to false I get my result but how can I do it on following way

User.php

```
public function deliverydetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne(DeliveryDetails::class);
}

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($user){
        $user->deliverydetails()->create([
            'billname' => $user->name, 
        ]);
    });
}
```

DeliveryDetails.php

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

viewpage

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="billname" name="billname" value="{{$deliveryDetails->name}}"                                 class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
  <span style="color: red;">{{$errors->first('billname')}}</span>
</div>
```

productController

```
$deliveryDetailsCount = DeliveryDetails::where('user_id', $userid)->count(); 

    if($deliveryDetailsCount > 0){
        
        $deliveryDetails = DeliveryDetails::where('user_id', $userid)->first(); 
    }

if(request()->isMethod('post')){

        $this->validateDetails();

        $data = request()->all(); 
        // echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
        User::where('id', $userid)->update(['name'=>$data['name'], 'address'=>$data['address'],
        'city'=>$data['city'], 'state'=>$data['state'], 'country'=>$data['country'],
        'pincode'=>$data['pincode']]); 

        if($deliveryDetailsCount > 0){
            //update address
            DeliveryDetails::where('user_id', $userid)->update(['name'=>$data['billname'], 'address'=>$data['billaddress'],
            'city'=>$data['billcity'], 'state'=>$data['billstate'], 'country'=>$data['billcountry'],
            'pincode'=>$data['billpincode']]);
        }
        else{
            //add new address
            $c = new DeliveryDetails;
            $c->user_id = $userid;
            $c->email = $useremail;
            $c->name = $data['billname'];
            $c->save();
        }
}
```

how can I solve the issue..

Comment: In which line you get the error?

Comment: Have you checked the value of $data['name'] when getting the request?

Comment: actually my problem is $deliveryDetails is become undefined variable bcos there is no value thats why I use  the static function

Comment: Please add the code of the `deliveryDetails` method of the user model

Comment: I already added